# Count records having three or more items

Tags: django, annotate, summarization

I'd like to group records in two categories:

1. Items having three or more records
2. Items having less than three items

How do I go about this?  I'm looking at using annotate().

Comment: Please give more details. It is difficult to understand what you want to do

Comment: Please show your models and what the results should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
q = Book.objects.annotate(num_authors=Count('authors'))
books_with_3_or_over_authors = q.filter(num_authors__gte=3)
books_with_less_than_3_authors = q.filter(num_authors__lt=3)
```